# How can I die from falling?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

When falling in Final Fantasy 14, I get damage based on the height.

I fall a lot (mostly on purpose, love to see the Chocobo fly! ;)) and so far died from falling only once, and can't reproduce it.

Even falling from very high places (with or without Chocobo) leaves me alive, with 1 HP.

I don't remember where I fell and died (just that it was *not* on purpose, I actually fell), it was when I was around level 10. Maybe with low HP falling can kill you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only die from fall damage if you're in combat with something, otherwise you'll be left with 1 HP no matter how far you fall.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I don't think there's an official declaration from SQEX, it's one of those mechanics you just have to learn. But here's [a post from the official FFXIV forum](https://forum.square-enix.com/ffxiv/threads/186326) asking for the same question, having the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You either were in an instance (dungeon, etc.) when you died or something killed you right after you landed and you didn't notice.

As it stands there is no way to die from falling from any height outside of instanced battles (at least not from the fall itself) in FFXIV, at most you can land in the middle of a pack of aggressive mobs and they kill you faster than your health can regenerate after your fall.

It's on the list with not drowning when under water with ways in which the world of FFXIV is not like our own.

Comment: You can certainly die from fall damage in the open world. If you are in combat fall damage is uncapped, meaning the fall itself, and not damage from another source, can kill you. If you are not in combat, you will always be left with 1 HP after taking fall damage.

The devs have actually disabled fall damage entirely in most instanced duties and they now use kill planes to kill you whenever falling is supposed to kill you, so it is generally impossible to die from fall damage inside of a dungeon or trial now, although that was not always the case. A good example of this is Titan.

Answer (score 1):

Something above level 10 probably attacked you the instant you hit the ground. It happens quickly if you fall next to an enemy and happens to most players at least once. The second you die, the enemy will de-agro, so it might look like they never even attacked you to begin with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There already is a much more sensible answer. Please read through other answers before writing one yourself.

Comment: @Joachim and reviewers: actually the answer does give extra details that aren't part of the other answers, and as I was told myself when asking for reference: "I don't think there's an official declaration from SQEX, it's one of those mechanics you just have to learn" and that answer has 10 upvotes without any reference link. I honestly can't see any reason to remove this answer.